# Where to find virtual host details and document root in Ubuntu Hardy?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, virtualhost, ubuntu-8.04

Where to find virtual host details and document root in Ubuntu Hardy?

For example, in Centos both information is available in httpd.conf file, whilst there is also a httpd.conf file found in Hardy, virtual hosts and document root information is not available.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available
```

and use **a2ensite** to enable sites which symlink them to: `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled.`

All you have to do is create a file and then enable the site, restart apache2 and the site should be enabled and working so long as you entered the virtual host configuration properly.

Comment: no problem. everyone starts somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I believe the response given above response is rather incomplete.

**Documentroot** is under: /var/www
That is where your index.html or link thereto should be placed.

**TEST**: If your apache2.2 is properly installed with default settings, and you type-in http://localhost/ in your browser, by default you should get a page with:

It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.